# Arduino controlled boost converter

Tags: arduino, boost, io

If I was to build a 12->65V boost converter using [Texas's LM5002](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5002.pdf) regulator IC, would it be possible to tie an Arduino I/O pin directly to the EN pin to enable/disable the output, while keeping the 12V at Vin? I would only need a small output current (around 0.1 mA)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2favRi9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the data sheet:

> The LM5002 contains a dual level Enable circuit. When the EN pin voltage is below 450 mV, the IC is in a low current shutdown mode with the VCC LDO disabled. When the EN pin voltage is raised above the shutdown threshold but below the 1.26V standby threshold, the VCC LDO regulator is enabled, while the remainder of the IC is disabled. When the EN pin voltage is raised above the 1.26V standby threshold, all functions are enabled and normal operation begins. An internal 6 μA current source pulls up the EN pin to activate the IC when the EN pin is left disconnected.<

If you hook a five volt digital pin up to the EN pin it will fully enable the chip. However, you would need a way to power the Arduino with the correct voltage (probably not 12v) and should hook the ground of the IC to the Arduino ground to prevent different ground voltages.

Comment: I've thought about using Arduino's 5V to supply the regulator (it would probably be able to source the necessary current), but 5>65V might be a bit too steep for a conventional boost topology, thus using a 12V supply to power both the regulator and the arduino (12>5 dc converter) seems like the best option